# ionic native geofence iOS Compile error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

Please help me out from this error:

**ionic Native + geofance + iOS**

```
ios compile error after install geofence plugin.

================== Compile error is ===============

The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Volumes/TimeMachine/AtoZ_Projects/Mobile_Apps/InstaPlace/InstaPlace/platforms/ios/InstaPlace/Plugins/cordova-plugin-geofence/GeofencePlugin.swift
    CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Volumes/TimeMachine/AtoZ_Projects/Mobile_Apps/InstaPlace/InstaPlace/platforms/ios/InstaPlace/Plugins/cordova-plugin-geofence/SwiftData.swift
    CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Volumes/TimeMachine/AtoZ_Projects/Mobile_Apps/InstaPlace/InstaPlace/platforms/ios/InstaPlace/Plugins/cordova-plugin-geofence/SwiftyJson.swift
    CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(4 failures)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Volumes/TimeMachine/AtoZ_Projects/Mobile_Apps/InstaPlace/InstaPlace/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,InstaPlace.xcworkspace,-scheme,InstaPlace,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone SE,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Volumes/TimeMachine/AtoZ_Projects/Mobile_Apps/InstaPlace/InstaPlace/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Volumes/TimeMachine/AtoZ_Projects/Mobile_Apps/InstaPlace/InstaPlace/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build ios (exit code 1).

==========================
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got success after following this steps.

1 - uninstall geofence plugin.

2 - uninstall platform iOS

3 - install geofence plugin.

4 - replace these 3 file [geofence plugin files](https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence/tree/master/src/ios)

5 - install the platform iOS.

6 - build success.

thanks.